# React Invalid Hook Call Warning in BrowserRouter Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faImage } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const galleryData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593053109521-e86fd978ba96?q=80&w=1674&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D',
    title: 'Beautiful Sunset',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
}
];

const Home = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <div className='heading' style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage} size='lg' />
      <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
    <button title='View More'>
      <Link to="/gallery">See Images</Link>
    </button>
  </div>
);

const Gallery = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <div className='heading' style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage} size='lg' />
      <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    </div>
    <div className='gallery'>
      {galleryData.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id} className="gallery-item">
          <img src={item.imageUrl} alt={item.title} />
          <div className="caption">
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const Nav = () => (
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/gallery">Gallery</Link>
      </li>
      {/* Add more navigation links as needed */}
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )};

export default App;
```

I've checked for the common reasons mentioned in the warning message, such as version mismatches and breaking the Rules of Hooks, but I couldn't identify the root cause. The error seems to be related to the BrowserRouter component.

Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? `<Routes>` looks like v6, but `exact component={Home}` looks like v5

Comment: I agree with @NicholasTower here; I don't see any other issues but the incorrect `Route` props. Please ensure you have all the ***correct*** versions of project dependencies installed. If necessary, delete your `node_modules` directory and re-run `npm install` and then restart the project.

Answer (score -1):

Try use the original name of the BrowserRouter, instead of a the assigning Router name.
Because React Router Dom library just have the Router function exported of the own library, maybe something is conflicting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I do not see there is any problem in the hooks. Since you say you do not have version mismatches, can you check for more than one copy of react ?

```
yarn list react
// or
npm ls react
```

This helps you to indentify if there are multiple versions installed.